# Formatting Windows timestamp using Logstash

Tags: windows, logging, event-log, logstash

I have successfully integrated Windows Event logs to Logstash.
the timestamp on windows event logs looks like this: `20131007071942.087375-000`

To convert this timestamp into a readable one i have used the date filter on logstash.

```
date{
  match => [ "TimeGenerated", "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ssssss-sss" ]
}
```

This gives me this error :

```
 ←[33mFailed parsing date from field {:field=>"TimeGenerated", :value=>"20131007080720.040037-
000", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20131007080720.040037-
000" is too short, :level=>:warn}←[0m
```

It would be great if someone could help me to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the grok debugger:

http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

and looking at the existing regex patterns: https://github.com/logstash/logstash/tree/master/patterns

To get you started:

%{YEAR:YYYY}%{MONTHNUM:MM}%{MONTHDAY:dd}%{GREEDYDATA:remainder}